# Series Expansion by differentiation

Tags: calculus, power-series

We know that **1/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+....x^n**

Say we need to find a suitable function for the expansion **x+x^2+x^3+x^4+....x^(n+1)**

We would differentiate **1/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+....x^n**

This would yield 1/(1-x)^2 =  1 + 2x+3x^2+4x^3 +...+nx^(n-1)**

Multiplying it by x would yield **x/(1-x)^2 = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 +...nx^n**  Hence the respective function would be **x/(1 - x)^2 = x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 +...nx^n**

But how would we obtain the function g[x] for the expansion **1+ 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 +...**

Comment: For the expansion of $x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots$, just factor out $x$ in each term.

Comment: but that would only produce 1+x+x^2...wouldn't it and not 1+2x^2+3x^3+....

Comment: Right, it was just a remark about your initial question. It thought the final aim  was the initial question. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The question was how would we obtain 1+ 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 +... from 1/(1-x) with the nth terms included in the expansion as well. I tried differentiating the 1/(1-x) and its expansion , integration and the works but to no avail

Comment: @dodgevipert56 Then you are looking for the sum not the series. You should revise your question to make it more clear on that point.

Comment: Is it not $\color{red}x+2x^2+3x^3+\dotsm $?

Answer (score 2):

Your work is fine, now we just have to subtract $x$ and add $1$ that is

$$g(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}-x+1$$

Comment: But what would the format be in terms of n?

Comment: @dodgevipert56 $g(x)$ is the value of $1+ 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 +...+nx^n$ in the limit as $n\to \infty$ (for $|x|<1$).

Comment: @dodgevipert56 Also $1/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+....x^n$ is not  true. If you want the finite sum you should start from $(1-x^n)/(1-x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+....x^n$.